# link scattered ui to one controller in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I join multiple scattered UI components, other than using multiple ng-controller directives? I saw an advices of creating some kind of UI service, but I don't know how to call service methods from ng-click.

In code below i have form for adding list items, but it is in overlay, while items themself should be in `<div id="page"></div>`, so how do I link it all together?

---

`html:`

```
<body ng-app="app">
    <div id="overlay">
        <div class="overlayPage" id="addSiteForm" ng-controller="SitesController">
            <h2>Add site</h2>
            <div class="inputContainer">
                <p>Title</p>
                <input type="text" id="addSiteTitle" ng-model="newSite.title">
            </div>
            <div class="inputContainer">
                <p>URL</p>
                <input type="text" id="addSiteUrl" ng-model="newSite.url">
            </div>
            <div class="buttonContainer right">
                <button id="addSiteSumit" ng-click="addSite()">Add</button>
                <button id="addSiteCancel" ng-click="hideOverlay()">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="header">
        <h1>New tab</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="headerButtons">
        <div id="addSiteButton" class="headerButton" ng-controller="SitesController" ng-click="showOverlay()"><p>Add site</p></div>
        <div id="settingsButton" class="headerButton"><p>Settings</p></div>
    </div>
    <div id="page"></div>
    <div id="actionBar">
        <div class="actionPage shown" id="mainActionPage">
            <div class="action siteBoxAction" id="deleteButton"><p>Delete</p></div>
            <div class="action siteBoxAction" id="resizeButton"><p>Resize</p></div>
            <div class="action siteBoxAction" id="editButton"><p>Edit</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="actionPage" id="resizeActionPage">
            <div class="action back"><p>Back</p></div>
            <div class="action size small"><p>Small</p></div>
            <div class="action size normal"><p>Normal</p></div>
            <div class="action size large"><p>Large</p></div>
            <div class="action size icon"><p>Icon</p></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

---

`SitesController:`

```
app.controller('SitesController', function($scope, SitesFactory){
    $scope.sites = SitesFactory.getSites();
    console.log($scope.sites);
    $scope.addSite = function(){
        console.log($scope.newSite);
        // code for adding site
    }
    $scope.showOverlay = function(){
        $('#overlay').addClass('shown');
    }
    $scope.hideOverlay = function(){
        $('#overlay').removeClass('shown');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could move your ng-controller="SitesController" directive to the body tag and remove it from the inner divs.  That will allow all of the inner divs to use SitesController.